# Sapling tree gen add-on - rotate branches longitudinally

Tags: sapling-addon

I am interested in creating a fern with this tool. Unfortunately I can't get the 3rd level branches to rotate so that they're facing the sky, instead it only seems possible to have them parallel to the 1st branch (trunk) whereas I want them perpendicular. "Split angle" seems like the correct property to change but it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

I have set the "rotate angle" to 180 so that they're all parallel with each other, unfortunately I can't get them to all rotate 90 degrees.

[image: screenshot]

I am using Blender 2.79b but also tried this on 2.90 and had the same problem. Is what I want actually possible with this add-on?